# R code: group_by() and mutate() to create new column with group means is not working

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to create a new column in a dataframe that includes the average score for a site based on multiple observations. There are 110 Sites on two Dates with multiple Scores:

```
 A tibble: 4,706 × 4
   Site  Date     Score Label
   <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>
 1 BRY1  20210616 0.456 CONI 
 2 BRY1  20210616 0.355 CONI 
 3 BRY1  20210616 0.462 CONI 
 4 BRY1  20210616 0.945 CONI 
 5 BRY1  20210616 0.953 CONI 
 6 BRY1  20210616 0.942 CONI 
 7 BRY1  20210616 0.766 CONI 
 8 BRY1  20210616 0.899 CONI 
 9 BRY1  20210616 0.918 CONI 
10 BRY1  20210616 0.943 CONI

df <- read.table(text = "
RN   Site  Date     Score Label
 1 BRY1  20210616 0.456 CONI 
 2 BRY1  20210616 0.355 CONI 
 3 BRY1  20210616 0.462 CONI 
 4 BRY1  20210616 0.945 CONI 
 5 BRY1  20210616 0.953 CONI 
 6 BRY1  20210616 0.942 CONI 
 7 BRY1  20210616 0.766 CONI 
 8 BRY1  20210616 0.899 CONI 
 9 BRY1  20210616 0.918 CONI 
10 BRY1  20210616 0.943 CONI", header = TRUE)
```

I want a new column that gives the average Score for each Site/Date combination.

I used the following code:

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Site, Date) %>% 
  mutate(avgScore = mean(Score))
```

But this just yields a new column with the average Score overall, instead of by group:

```
# A tibble: 4,706 × 5
# Groups:   Site, Date [104]
   Site  Date     Score Label avgScore
   <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
 1 BRY1  20210616 0.456 CONI     0.755
 2 BRY1  20210616 0.355 CONI     0.755
 3 BRY1  20210616 0.462 CONI     0.755
 4 BRY1  20210616 0.945 CONI     0.755
 5 BRY1  20210616 0.953 CONI     0.755
 6 BRY1  20210616 0.942 CONI     0.755
 7 BRY1  20210616 0.766 CONI     0.755
 8 BRY1  20210616 0.899 CONI     0.755
 9 BRY1  20210616 0.918 CONI     0.755
10 BRY1  20210616 0.943 CONI     0.755
```

Not exactly sure where I am stumbling. Appreciate the help :)

Comment: Try using `dplyr::mutate` instead of only `mutate`. `dplyr::mutate` function is probably masked by `plyr::mutate`

Comment: Also, your data here has only one group, so even if corrected we'll see only one unique value here

Comment: Relevant though not a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28812512/3358272

Comment: ... these seem better dupe candidates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26106146/3358272 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/26923862/3358272

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does summarize or mutate not work with group\_by when I load \`plyr\` after \`dplyr\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106146/why-does-summarize-or-mutate-not-work-with-group-by-when-i-load-plyr-after-dp)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not working?

With your example data you only have one Site and one Date:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Site, Date) %>% 
  mutate(avgScore = mean(Score))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 6
#> # Groups:   Site, Date [1]
#>       RN Site      Date Score Label avgScore
#>    <int> <chr>    <int> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1     1 BRY1  20210616 0.456 CONI     0.764
#>  2     2 BRY1  20210616 0.355 CONI     0.764
#>  3     3 BRY1  20210616 0.462 CONI     0.764
#>  4     4 BRY1  20210616 0.945 CONI     0.764
#>  5     5 BRY1  20210616 0.953 CONI     0.764
#>  6     6 BRY1  20210616 0.942 CONI     0.764
#>  7     7 BRY1  20210616 0.766 CONI     0.764
#>  8     8 BRY1  20210616 0.899 CONI     0.764
#>  9     9 BRY1  20210616 0.918 CONI     0.764
#> 10    10 BRY1  20210616 0.943 CONI     0.764
```

This is the expected outcome for your example data.

If you change the number of Sites and/or Dates, you get a different averages for each group, e.g. with altered example data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "RN   Site  Date     Score Label
 1 BRY1  20210616 0.456 CONI 
 2 BRY1  20210616 0.355 CONI 
 3 BRY2  20210616 0.462 CONI 
 4 BRY2  20210616 0.945 CONI 
 5 BRY3  20210616 0.953 CONI 
 6 BRY3  20210617 0.942 CONI 
 7 BRY4  20210617 0.766 CONI 
 8 BRY4  20210617 0.899 CONI 
 9 BRY5  20210617 0.918 CONI 
10 BRY5  20210617 0.943 CONI", header = TRUE)

df %>%
  group_by(Site, Date) %>% 
  mutate(avgScore = mean(Score))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 6
#> # Groups:   Site, Date [6]
#>       RN Site      Date Score Label avgScore
#>    <int> <chr>    <int> <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1     1 BRY1  20210616 0.456 CONI     0.406
#>  2     2 BRY1  20210616 0.355 CONI     0.406
#>  3     3 BRY2  20210616 0.462 CONI     0.704
#>  4     4 BRY2  20210616 0.945 CONI     0.704
#>  5     5 BRY3  20210616 0.953 CONI     0.953
#>  6     6 BRY3  20210617 0.942 CONI     0.942
#>  7     7 BRY4  20210617 0.766 CONI     0.832
#>  8     8 BRY4  20210617 0.899 CONI     0.832
#>  9     9 BRY5  20210617 0.918 CONI     0.930
#> 10    10 BRY5  20210617 0.943 CONI     0.930
```

If you want a summary of the averages, instead of a column listing the average on every row, you can use the `summarise()` function from the dplyr package, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "RN   Site  Date     Score Label
 1 BRY1  20210616 0.456 CONI 
 2 BRY1  20210616 0.355 CONI 
 3 BRY2  20210616 0.462 CONI 
 4 BRY2  20210616 0.945 CONI 
 5 BRY3  20210616 0.953 CONI 
 6 BRY3  20210617 0.942 CONI 
 7 BRY4  20210617 0.766 CONI 
 8 BRY4  20210617 0.899 CONI 
 9 BRY5  20210617 0.918 CONI 
10 BRY5  20210617 0.943 CONI", header = TRUE)

df %>%
  group_by(Site, Date) %>% 
  summarise(avgScore = mean(Score))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Site'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#> # Groups:   Site [5]
#>   Site      Date avgScore
#>   <chr>    <int>    <dbl>
#> 1 BRY1  20210616    0.406
#> 2 BRY2  20210616    0.704
#> 3 BRY3  20210616    0.953
#> 4 BRY3  20210617    0.942
#> 5 BRY4  20210617    0.832
#> 6 BRY5  20210617    0.930
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-10 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I would probably create new dataframes for each example, instead of repeatedly overwriting `df`